# ArchLinux problems with wireless

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, arch-linux

I recently followed this tutorial on [installing arch-linux](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFvJ09LWwZA).

During that tutorial and connected to a wireless network (WPA2+PSK) through my linksys wireless adapter (WUSB54GR) using the 'wifi-menu' program, and it worked like a charm, I didn't even have to install drivers; I just selected my network and entered the encryption key.

When I installed arch and logged in, I no longer had access to wireless connection; and when I did the command:

> wifi-menu

The console says:

> Please install 'dialog' to use wifi-menu

So I tried doing 'sudo pacman -S dialog', but obviously this did not work, as I did not have an internet connection.

What do?

BTW I have no ethernet ports on this pc so I cannot hook it up directly to the router.

Answer (score 3):

Refering to a post in another forum:

---

wifi-menu is a part of the netcfg package. 
If you did not install it, you won't have it available.
Your options are either establishing the connection using the ip, iw... and wpa_supplicant tools manually or downloading the packages netcfg, dialog and ncurses manually on an usb stick and install them with `pacman -U package.pkg.tar.gz`

You can find the download in the [package database](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/)

Your other option is to boot with the install medium again, connect to the internet, mount your arch installation, chroot and install netcfg.

---

[Source](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=148959)

Once again, google saves the day.

Comment: Thanks, I installed those three packages from the repos. But now when I run 'wifi-menu' I get the message '> No such interface: wlan0'

Comment: have you started and flagged as start on boot the services?

Answer (score 2):

in a terminal type:
**ip a**

to show all your available network cards. One should be named 'wlp1s0' or the like. This is your wireless device. Now just add it to the wifi-menu call.
**sudo wifi-menu wlp1s0**

If you do not see any wifi device with ip a, then you have to start dhcpcd.
**sudo dhcpcd**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

- You have at least the `dhcpcd`, `iw`, and `wpa_supplicant` packages installed.
- The wireless driver that you are using uses the mac80211 API. Some
  problematic ones don't.
- Your network is provisioned using DHCP.
- Your base station doesn't "hide" the SSID. It's a bad idea
  from a security standpoint, and contravenes some standards. See this [Microsoft
  Technet article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2008/02/08/non-broadcast-wireless-ssids-why-hidden-wireless-networks-are-a-bad-idea.aspx),
  whilst ignoring the Windows-specific parts.

About not having to install drivers, you actually did, since they are in-kernel
(or kernel modules). Most Linux wireless drivers worth their salt are in-tree.

FYI, "RSN" == "WPA2".

Substitute $DEV, $SSID and $PSK appropriately.

$MAC, $BSSID, and $FREQ are just for reference. You don't need to figure them
out yourself.

Where "#" represents the root user prompt…

1. Create a file named /etc/wpa_supplicant/$SSID according to the following
   template.

   ```
   ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant

   network={
          ssid="$SSID"
          scan_ssid=1
          proto=RSN
          key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
          pairwise=CCMP
          group=CCMP
          psk="$PSK"
   }
   ```

   By the way, implementation of CCMP is mandatory for *WPA2*. Don't use TKIP.
   It's been broken. It should soon, if not already, be disallowed by the Wi-Fi
   alliance.
2. Associate with the base station, authenticate, authorize yourself.

   ```
   # wpa_supplicant -i $DEV -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/$SSID -D nl80211 -B
   ```
3. Check that you are authenticated and authorized.

   ```
   # wpa_cli
   > status 
   bssid=$BSSID
   ssid=$SSID
   id=0
   mode=station
   pairwise_cipher=CCMP
   group_cipher=CCMP
   key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
   wpa_state=COMPLETED
   address=$MAC
   ```

   Poll with the `status` command until you are, or look for messages like the
   following.

   ```
   <3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS 
   <3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE 
   <3>SME: Trying to authenticate with $BSSID (SSID='$SSID' freq=$FREQ MHz)
   <3>Trying to associate with $BSSID (SSID='$SSID' freq=$FREQ MHz)
   <3>Associated with $BSSID
   <3>WPA: Key negotiation completed with $BSSID [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
   <3>CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to $BSSID completed [id=0 id_str=]
   ```
4. Get an address using DHCP.

   ```
   # dhcpcd $DEV
   ```
5. Install the `dialog` package, *as a dependancy*.

   ```
   # pacman -S --asdep dialog
   ```